# reading json hierarchy in php

Tags: php, mysql, json

I am trying to map a json file to a mysql database with the following json file:

```
configurationItems":[  
  {  
     "configurationItemVersion":"1.0",
     "configurationItemCaptureTime":"2014-12-05T10:22:51.751Z",
     "configurationStateId":1,
     "relatedEvents":[  ],
     "awsAccountId":"a value",
     "configurationItemStatus":"ResourceDiscovered",
     "resourceId":"some resource",
     "ARN":"blah blah",
     "awsRegion":"us-east-1",
     "availabilityZone":"us-east-1b",
     "configurationStateMd5Hash":"string",
     "resourceType":"AWS::EC2::Instance",
     "resourceCreationTime":"2014-01-06T10:37:37.000Z",
     "tags":{  },
     "relationships":[  ],
     "configuration":{  
        "instanceId":"",
        "imageId":"",
        "state":{  },
        "privateDnsName":"",
        "publicDnsName":"",
        "stateTransitionReason":"
        "keyName":"production-us",
        "amiLaunchIndex":0,
        "productCodes":[  ],
        "instanceType":"m2.xlarge",
        "launchTime":"ts",
        "placement":{  },
        "kernelId":"1",
        "monitoring":{  },
        "subnetId":"",
        "vpcId":"",
        "privateIpAddress":"",
        "stateReason":{  },
        "architecture":",
        "rootDeviceType":"",
        "rootDeviceName":"",
        "blockDeviceMappings":[  
           {  
              "deviceName":"namr",
              "ebs":{  
                 "volumeId":"vol-eb90e1a6",
                 "status":"attached",
                 "attachTime":"2014-01-06T10:37:40.000Z",
                 "deleteOnTermination":true
              }
           }
        ],
        "virtualization
```

the way in which I have been accessing using php is as follows

```
$value_wanted=$parent["child1"]["child2"]["value"];
```

I am having a problem accessing blockDeviceMappings device name as using my theory which has worked up until now it would be

```
  $deviceName=$configurationItems["configuration"]["blockDeviceMappings"]    ["deviceName"];
```

I have tried

```
    $deviceName=$configurationItems["configuration"]["blockDeviceMappings"]   [""]["deviceName"];
```

but that does not work either its really the empty bracket that I think is throwing me any advice is always appreciated.

Comment: $deviceName=$configurationItems["configuration"]["blockDeviceMappings"]   [0]["deviceName"];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`blockDeviceMappings` is an array of objects. If it always has only one item (as shown):

```
$deviceName=$configurationItems["configuration"]["blockDeviceMappings"][0]["deviceName"];
```

else you will need to iterate the array:

```
foreach($configurationItems["configuration"]["blockDeviceMappings"] as $mapping)
    echo $mapping['deviceName'];
```

EDIT as per your comment, `ebs` is a sibling of `deviceName` not a decendent.

The correct way to access `volumeId` it would be:

```
$deviceName=$configurationItems["configuration"]["blockDeviceMappings"][0]["ebs"]["volumeId"];
```

Comment: many thanks for your answer the json is as shown and solution 1 worked however when I try and put volumeId into my ebs table I get an error of illegal string offset ebs using '$volumeId=$configurationItems["configuration"]["blockDeviceMappings"] [0]["deviceName"]["ebs"]["volumeId"];' any ideas ?

Comment: worked it out thanks its always the daft things appreciate the help